# Terminal Background in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04, I was configuring the terminal, but I can't change the background of it to transparent. There is an option, but it doesn't work, please help me.

Comment: You can't right now. It's a bug. See [here on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1292282?comments=all).

Answer (score 3):

The terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 supports profiles. In order to get a transparent terminal follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal
2. Select *Profile preferences* in the menu *Edit*
3. Select the *Background* tab
4. Check the *Transparent background* radio button
5. Adjust the *Shade background or image background* slider to your preference

You could also select *Profiles* in the menu *Edit* and create a new profile so you can easily switch between the default and the transparent background (and other settings).

Comment: Oh!, Yes, I forget to say that I test on ubuntu 14.04 gnome 3.10 desktop, in unity desktop it option works correctly but not in gnome 3.10, any idea?, thank you so much

Comment: @user270646 please add this information to the question. I'll write an answer about how to get a workaround for this problem as soon as I'm on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been removed from gnome-terminal, canonical added a workaround for unity but under gnome-shell this workaround doesn't work.

There's an interesting discussion on the subject on the gnome bugzilla here:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=698544

Until they decide to re-add the feature it seems xfce4-terminal or konsole are going to have to be your 'work around'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
**menu > edit > Profile Preferences > Background**

**Then choose Transparent background.**
You can also use "Shade transparent or image background" slider to control the transparency.

The above works for me, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Oh!, Yes, I forget to say that I test on ubuntu 14.04 gnome 3.10 desktop, in unity desktop it option works correctly but not in gnome 3.10, any idea?, thank you so much