# Ubuntu 14 lubuntu terminal transparency does not work

Tags: 14.04, command-line, lubuntu, transparency, terminator

I have tried [other related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450135/terminal-background-in-ubuntu) on lubuntu desktop, on Ubuntu 14, on my Lenovo Laptop Z50. But the screen is not transparent.

Answer (score 3):

I found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Windows) a way of making windows transparent in Lubuntu. Just a CTRL + C - CTRL + V to grant the material isn't going to be lost so soon:

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr transset
```

Here it complained about not finding the `transset`. So I tried installing just the `xcompmgr` and everything worked fine.

To get xcompmgr running every time:

```
leafpad ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

and add the line:

```
@xcompmgr -c
```

which turns on translucency and soft shadows. Fading can be added with -fD A where A is milliseconds between steps in a fade.

To control the level of opacity, make sure the program you want to change is running, then use:

```
transset B
```

where B is some number between 0 and 1 where 0 is completely transparent and 1 is completely opaque. It'll turn your cursor into Then click on the window you want to change the transparency on. If you like fading, you may want to add -F to xcompmgr to allow for faded transitions when changing opacity.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems like this is a problem with Ubuntu in general and is beyond the scope of AskUbuntu that terminal transparency doesn't work. If you've gotta have it, it is worth installing Terminator which is a more advanced terminal emulator that supports transparency as well as a wealth of other features that you may or may not want to use.

Comment: I installed Terminator too, same result.